# vuex 3.6 why is my state object undefined when using it inside a method

Tags: vue.js, vuex, action

I am building an application using vue 2.6.11 and vuex 3.6.0

The page I am building is for an event registration.  The ActiveEvent is fetched from the database (Event ID, Date, Location etc) using an API

The registration form first asks for an email address.  On blur of the email field we then fire the checkEmail().  This should do one or two API calls. The first call checks to see if we have the email address in the database and returns the ParticipantID, and if we do then a second call is made to see if the participant is already registered against this event using Event.EventID and ActiveUser.ParticipantID

The stucture of the page being loaded is a page component **<EventDetail>** called from the router. This has a main component  **<EventRegistration>** which calls two separate sub-components: **<EventRegistrationBlurb>** which gets the state.ActiveEvent passed as a prop and **<EventRegistrationForm>** which is fetching the state.ActiveEvent directly. The outer component **<EventRegistration>** is responsible for fetching the Event data from the API and setting state.ActiveEvent which is does successfully,

What I am failing to understand is why when I call checkEmail in my component, this.ActiveEvent is undefined.  The puter component is fetching the API and setting the state correctly as the blurb component is correctly rendering it. If I put the ActiveEvent object into the template for the EventRegistrationForm it renders correctly, it is just not being set in time for the binding to be made to the method checkEmail()

I have the following code in my sub-component **<EventRegistrationForm>**: (NOTE, ActiveEvent is set by an outer component and does get set correctly)

```
 methods: {
    ...mapActions(['CheckParticipantByEmail']),
    async checkEmail () {
      const payload = {
        email: this.form.email,
        EventID: this.ActiveEvent.EventID  // <-- THIS IS UNDEFINED???
    }
    await this.CheckParticipantByEmail(payload)
  }
},
computed: {
  ...mapState(['ActiveEvent', 'ActiveUser'])
}
```

and then in my store:

```
state: {
  ActiveEvent: {},
  ActiveUser: {}
},
mutations: {
  SET_ACTIVE_EVENT (state, payload) {
    state.ActiveEvent = payload
  },
  CHECK_PARTICIPANT_BY_EMAIL (state, payload) {
    state.ActiveUser = payload
  },
  GET_PARTICIPANT_FOR_EVENT (state, payload) {
    state.ActiveUser = payload
  }
},
actions: {
  async CheckParticipantByEmail ({ commit }, payload) {
    console.log('payload', payload)
    const baseUrl = process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL
    const url = `${baseUrl}getParticipantbyEmail`
    const { email, EventID } = payload
    const response = await axios.post(
      url,
      {
        EmailAddress: email
      }
    )
    const User = await response.data[0]
    commit('CHECK_PARTICIPANT_BY_EMAIL', User)
    if (User.ParticipantID > 0) {
      const baseUrl = process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL
      const url2 = `${baseUrl}getParticipantForEvent`
      const payload2 = {
        ParticipantID: User.ParticipantID,
        EventID: EventID
      }
      alert('URL2: ' + url2)
      alert('payload2 participant: ' + payload2.ParticipantID)
      alert('payload2 event: ' + payload2.EventID)
      const response2 = await axios.post(
        url2,
        payload2
      )
      // console.log('response: ', response.data[0])
      const payload3 = response2.data[0]
      commit('GET_PARTICIPANT_FOR_EVENT', payload3)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't use SET_ACTIVE_EVENT anywhere. Even if you do, make sure you do this before  accessing ActiveEvent

Comment: Thanks Etus,  It is called from a dispatched action in the outer component.  It is not an async timing thing because there is a significant delay between the API call and the triggering of the method when the user enters their email address

Answer (score 0):

As usual, it turns out to be an interface error between the chair and the keyboard.  This page is normally accessed from a list of events which is an array of objects where the identifier is EventID.  When calling the separate events the identifier is just ID so the code in the payload2 should read

```
const payload2 = {
    ParticipantID: User.ParticipantID,
    EventID: ID // <- NOTE change of identifier.
  }
```

I think I will update the API to return a consistent identifier and avoid the headache later on.  Only wasted about 3 hours on this...